# How to get mobile velocity in gwt device?

Tags: gwt, gps

Is it possible to calculate the velocity of the mobile device via any gwt api? I know the gps location is possible to be fetched, but how about velocity fetching from gps signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can Use [gwt-phonegap](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/).

Comment: Ok, it seems to come in same bunch with the coordinates. I did not think it was so easy. Thanks.